# Statically linked linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to compile a linux kernel such that the vmlinux has all the network drivers statically linked. I tried to disable CONFIG_MODULES, but that didnt do the trick.

Comment: Insufficient information... What architecture you are building for? Which defconfig or which Makefile rule you're using? Which specific modules you want to build as built-in raher than external modules?

Comment: Can do `make allyesconfig` as your first rough approach.

Answer (score 1):

To compile all your modules into the kernel statically, you have to change the appropriate configuration options from `m` to `y`.

Yes, all of them.